# Ionic Cordova Android App Minify APK using ProGuard

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, apk, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am trying to minify my apk using cordova-plugin-proguard.

What I have already tried is update the proguard-config with

**-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.***

or

**-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.****

But it doesnt help. What else can I do? I appreciate any help :)

```
> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
39 actionable tasks: 39 executed
C:\Dev\ionic-5-minify-project\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Dev\ionic-5-minify-project\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\nl\xservices\plugins\SocialSharing.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: there were 2 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt
Warning: there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
```